# Continuity-equivalent for Android

Tags: windows, android, synchronization

I would like to have my incoming/outgoing phone calls and text messages accessible on a Windows laptop when I am working on it. I currently use an Android phone manufactured by Samsung. My need is for an Android-equivalent to [Continuity for iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681).

Is there any tool that enables this, or any way to hack this together, without leaving my mobile device in "Developer-mode"?

Comment: I'd love to know if this is possible too.  Only thing I can think of is to use Google Voice/Hangouts; forward calls to the Voice number, using Hangouts on the desktop to take the calls and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Airdroid](https://www.airdroid.com/) for texting, accessing clipboard, installing apps and of course notification.

It also offers many other features for managing your phone wirelessly. For using it, both your phone and the computer should be connected to the same WiFi network.

Although, I don't know whether it supports phone calls or not.

Comment: Works really well over WiFi. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[MightyText](https://mightytext.net/) plus its browser addons allows you to text and receive phone notifications on your desktop, but unfortunately will not allow you to receive calls on it. However, it will inform you if you have at incoming call.

Comment: This looked promising but the linking to my Google account is stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: After using it for 2 days, I deleted it. Their website requires allowing third party cookies, and they seem fairly intrusive (accessing and mining contacts, no opt out, no transparency of data ownership, no exit protocols). On the other hand, customer support and feedback was excellent.